# Graph file attachment while email forward

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to attached a file while forwarding the email by using MS Graph. Are there any method to add the attachment in ForwardPostRequestBody?

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.Item.Forward.ForwardPostRequestBody
{
    Comment = "comment-value",
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Name = "name-value",
                Address = "address-value",
            },
        },
    },
};
await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Forward.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForwardPostRequestBody` has property `Message` where you can add `Attachments`.

When using `Message` then [do not use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `Comment` and `ToRecipients` of `ForwardPostRequestBody`.

Use `ToRecipients` and `Body` properties of the `Message`.

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("FilePath"));
var stringBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String);
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.Item.Forward.ForwardPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    Content = "comment-value"
                },
                Attachments = new List<Attachment>
                {
                    new FileAttachment
                    {
                        Name = "fileName",
                        ContentBytes = stringBytes
                    }
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "name-value",
                            Address = "address-value",
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        };
await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Forward.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I remove the `Body` object and keep the `Comment`. The `Body` will replace the Forward-Body Content.